# Multi Environment Azure Function

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-functions

I want to create an Azure function which is a queue trigger, that when it fires it connects to a SQL DB and gets a record and updates it.

How do I handle making sure the SQL connection queries the right database? Eg Staging DB vs Production DB

Do I need to have two instances of the same azure function? One that has it's connection string set in application settings to point to staging db and the other set to point at production db? Surely not?!

Every article I can find talks about your local.settings.json and production..which is fine. But in the real world we might have local, testing, staging, production.

I can pass through the environment as part of the queued message that comes into my Azure function, but surely there is a more elegant way and I'm missing something?

Comment: How do you switch your DB? With the queue content or with the function slots or other ways?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this depends on your solution design, size and deployment strategy. Here are 3 options:

Option 1 (our solution):
We are using Azure Functions in a large scale and 4 environments (DEV, TEST, STAGE, PROD).
Therefore, we've created a function for each instance having the right connection string on each stage.

Option 2:
Another possibility would be to create different deployment slots and -settings, then you could just use one function with different settings.

Option 3:
You could create parametrized settings and decide which one you might choose.

Comment: Gee... imagine if the docs actually made it as clear as you just did! Thanks @DSpirit

Comment: How do you handle the updates on one function to another? I mean you are saying that you created a function for each instance, let's say you made a change in the function that is for DEV, how do you update the function in other environments?

Comment: @BurakKarakuş we have deployment pipelines for each stage - so by adding any functionality, we deploy it to DEV at first and so on. Check this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/create-first-pipeline

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and comment @DSpirit, it worked like a charm. I think what AzureDocs team should do is to change their best practices recommendations to be more Azure Pipelines-centric.

Comment: Hi @DSpirit, Just to make it clear. In the first solution you describe, with **"we created a function for each instance"** are you meaning to **"we created a function _app_ for each instance"**?

Comment: @gersonZaragocin yes, each instance has its own function **app**, e.g. 
ordertrigger-dev, ...
ordertrigger-prod. In our scenario, this also included different virtual networks per environment.
But as abovementioned, it's not the only way to achieve this - I had customers that even had separate subscriptions for each environment, so the possibilities are just as dynamic as your requirements.